# Get exit code 1 on Makefile if statement

Tags: makefile, exit-code

I'm trying to get the exit code on the ifdef statement if the statement is not true, but I tried by using exit 1 and $(call exit 1)

when using the first on the following code I get "Makefile:11: *** missing separator.  Stop."

...

```
ifdef PACKAGE
    PACKAGEDIR = $(HOME)/$(PACKAGE)
else
    exit 1
endif
```

...

By using `$(call exit 1)` I get no error but the makefile still keeps executing.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to exit the Makefile on the else with the error code 1

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As geekosaur says you can't put a shell command like `exit 1` as a makefile operation.  Makefiles are not shell scripts, although they can *contain* shell scripts.  Shell commands can only appear within a target recipe, and nowhere else.

If you have a sufficiently new version of GNU make you can use the `$(error ...)` function, like this:

```
ifdef PACKAGE
    PACKAGEDIR = $(HOME)/$(PACKAGE)
else
    $(error You must define the PACKAGE variable)
endif
```

Also note that `ifdef` will be true if the variable is defined, *even if* it's defined to be the empty string.  You  may prefer:

```
ifneq ($(PACKAGE),)
    PACKAGEDIR = $(HOME)/$(PACKAGE)
else
    $(error You must define the PACKAGE variable)
endif
```

to ensure the variable is set to a non-empty value.

And, it's possible your version of GNU make is too old to support the `$(error ...)` function, although it's been around for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply have bare code sticking somewhere in a Makefile; code (such as `exit 1`) is always associated with a build rule of some kind.

In this case you want the [`$(error)` function](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html#Make-Control-Functions).  It may not be sufficient to drop it in the `else`, though, for the same reason that `exit 1` itself won't work there; you may need to rephrase the whole thing as

```
PACKAGEDIR := $(if $(flavor PACKAGE),undefined,$(error PACKAGE must be defined!),$(HOME)/$(PACKAGE))
```

Comment: Still not exit on error it continues and it sets package as undefined - undefined/SOURCES  fyi the code is not inside a target

Comment: The rephrased one would need to actually be used somewhere to trigger (this is true in general for `make`).  Your "fyi" is confused; a variable definition is not part of a target indeed, I was trying to tell you that your attempts to exit require being in a target.  Phrasing what you want is actually somewhat difficult, since you need to actually force expansion somewhere to trigger a `make` function (even `$(error)`).  Using `:=` as I have edited the answer to do *may* help.

Comment: @Gerardo, `$(error )` works for me in the `else` branch. Note the space before the `)`. What version of Make are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@exit 1`. An example:

```
ifdef PACKAGE
    PACKAGEDIR = $(HOME)/$(PACKAGE)
else
    @exit 1
endif
```